# How to fix a bad copy of Postgres dbs to a different machine?

Tags: postgresql

I had to copy over one set of DBs (around 2TB of data) from one machine to another one with 4TB of file system space. All databases are for internal usage only, no replica, no external writes.

The version of Postgres in both machines is the same (10.6).

What I did was physically "cp" files from one file system to another one, following the paths in `postgresql.conf` for the variable `data_directory` :

`cp -R /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/ /new_partition_path/postgresql/10`

then changed `data_directory` to `/new_partition_path/postgresql/10/main` and finally restarted postgres.

based on the default Ubuntu path.

Apparently all looked good, but now everytime I run some script (in parallel with 5/10 `psql` commands) I get strange errors like:

```
ERROR:  table "infix_final_pt_2" does not exist
STATEMENT:  drop table infix_final_pt_2
```

or

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "2" at character 61
STATEMENT:  drop table infix_final_pt_2
```

Like the table has not been built (even if the script for it run successfully).
The scripts have been used many times and they always worked.

I suspect that I did a bad job just copying over file system files. Can I recover somehow this situation? Maybe Postgres admin commands need to be run? I am not able to figure it out from the documentation.

Comment: What troubleshooting have you done so far? What were the results?

Comment: actually I have just copied over the data, run some usual scripts to build new data and that's it. I tried to run a single query manually instead of multiple queries in one script. In that case worked.

Comment: _copy over one set of DBs_: it's not possible to selectively copy some databases and not others. The entire instance must be copied and it must be shut down before. It's unclear in the question what procedure you followed exactly.

Comment: I haev updated my question. Also I have copied all, not only one db.

Comment: Have you installed same extensions in both servers?

Comment: Does the other machine have exactly the same OS? The same libc/locales?